# How to create a shared directory with read and write access to all applications in Android?

Tags: android, directory, shared

How do I create a shared directory with read/write permissions to all applications installed on my phone and that is not on the sdcard?
I tried that :

```
File f = new File("/tmp");
f.mkdir();
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way in Android would be to use ContentProvider.

A ContentProvider will be able to write File blobs.

See 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

Comment: sorry, haven't found any good examples. http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/ will cover some aspects though

Comment: But this is not the answer to the problem. I for once only found this question because I want to dump some data from an instrumentation test and certainly don't want to create a content provider just to debug the application. So how about answering the question: Where can one create a file without much fussing about?